# WPF Bind User Control Coordinates

Tags: wpf, canvas, binding, coordinates, two-way-binding

I have a User Control added to a Canvas. In another area of the application I have two TextBoxes that will get 2 values : X and Y. I need a two-way binding between the user control's top left corner coordinates and those 2 textboxes. 
I don't mind implementing a Converter or doing some calculations, but I need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<UserControl Canvas.Left="{Binding Text, ElementName=myFirstTextBox, Mode=TwoWays}"
             Canvas.Top="{Binding Text, ElementName=mySecondTextBox, Mode=TwoWays}"  ... />
```

But I can only strongly recommend you to use some sort of custom `ValidationRule` on your TextBoxes, in order to disallow any input that does not represent a valid number, otherwise you will get a nice crash.

Comment: Alternately, you can also bind from Text on your text box to {Binding (Canvas.Left), ElementName=myUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: Thanks Aurelien, I thought that would be more complicated.